# Ambiguous reference to debugging

Tags: c#

I've recently added a registration to my code and the main part of the code uses some debugging. I am now getting this error:

CS0104  C# 'Debug' is an ambiguous reference between 'CDBurnerXP.IO.Debug' and 'System.Diagnostics.Debug'

Comment: Use the fully qualified name: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have both references in your code, and they have the same base name 'Debug', and its confusing because it doesn't know which one to take. In order to stop having this error, you have to chose between which registration you want to use, and remove the references for the other.

**EDIT:** If you want to keep both references for somewhat reason, you can specify in the code the namespace, something like this:

- instead of having `Debug.Something` use `CDBurnerXP.IO.Debug.Something` or `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Something`